# pip3 update 9.0.1 to 9.0.3 get error

Tags: python-3.x, pip, updates

The error message:
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==9.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application

When i update pip3 get error.
I used commond:pip3 install -U pip
The error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwbaa.png)

And I change the pip3 requires to 9.0.3:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up9i0.png)

The error message changed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yITDn.png)

Where I wrong??